# Existence of a basis $B$ such that $M(\phi,B)=E$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Considering the matrix
>
> $$A=\begin{bmatrix}{2}&{1}&{0}\\{1}&{0}&{-1}\\{0}&{-1}&{-2}\end{bmatrix}\in M_3(R).$$
>    And $\phi:R^3 \times R^3\longrightarrow R$ the bilinear form  $\phi(v,w)=vAw^t$
>
> Find an orthogonal basis for $\phi.$
>
> Can we find a basis $B$ such that $M(\phi,B)=\begin{bmatrix}{-1}&{1}&{0}\\{1}&{-2}&{1}\\{0}&{1}&{-1}\end{bmatrix}$?

I have already calculated an orthogonal basis, which would be $\langle (1,0,0),(-1/2,1,0),(1,-2,1)\rangle$

However, I am stuck at the second part of the exercise. How can I know if that $B$ basis exists such that $M(\phi,B)=\begin{bmatrix}{-1}&{1}&{0}\\{1}&{-2}&{1}\\{0}&{1}&{-1}\end{bmatrix}$?

And if it exists, how can I find $B$?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure they are asking for an orthogonal basis for a bilinear form? It makes no sense, bases are for (sub-)spaces, not for bilinear forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the correct change for a quadratic form matrix is $P^T H P$ with nonsingular $P.$

It is not possible to solve $P^T AP = B$ because $A$ has one positive eigenvalue, one negative and one zero. However, $B$ has two negative eigenvalues and one zero.

Here is diagonal $P^T A P = D_A$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -2 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & -2
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & -\frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Here is diagonal $Q^T B Q = D_B$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
In $D_A$ and $D_B,$ **the nonzero diagonal entries are probably not eigenvalues**. In the first edition of Horn and Johnson, *Matrix Analysis*, on page 220, for real symmetric matrices, when $S$ is nonsingular and $B = SAS^T,$ then $A$ and $B$ are called congruent. They do use the word "diagonalize," but they are very careful, in the table on page 229, to have a column for "That which is to be diagonal" with different expression depending on conditions.

[Sylvester's_law_of_inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia)

It is not necessary to actually find the eigenvalues to confirm this. It is also not necessary to find the characteristic polynomial. The best way to proceed is to solve $P^T AP = D$ diagonal, where I got the diagonal entries as $(2, -1/2,0).$ For $B$ I got $(-1,-1,0).$

[reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)

Addendum: there seems to be some confusion on Sylvester. Here is an example I made up. The original symmetric matrix $C,$ all entries $\pm 1,$ has four positive entries on its diagonal. However, this disagrees with the counts in $D_C,$ which has three positive but one negative entry on the diagonal, and this is what is important for Inertia. 
Here is diagonal $R^T C R = D_C$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 2 & 0  \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 3
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
-8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 12 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 24
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Again, the eigenvalues of $C$ are not $-8,4,12,24.$ The eigenvalues of $C$ are  $-2,2,2,2.$ In fact, the columns of $R$ are eigenvectors and are perpendicular to each other, it is just that they vary in length, so $R$ is not actually orthogonal. Here is $CR:$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 3
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
-2 & -2 & -2 & -2 \\
-2 & 2 & -2 & -2 \\
-2 & 0 & 4 & -2 \\
-2 & 0 & 0 & 6
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: From Sylvester's Law of Inertia, do we just have to look at the diagonal and look at how $A$ has one positive entry and one negative entry while $B$ has three negative entries and then conclude that $P^TAP=B$ has no solution?

Comment: @NobleMushtak no, that is not enough

Comment: But according to the Wiki article, if $D=P^TAP$, then $D$ has the same number of positive elements in the diagonal as $A$ which is clearly not true for $A$ and $B$, so how come noticing this does not automatically show us that $P^TAP=B$ has no solutions? I am sorry if this seems rude; I am just trying to understand this law since I've never seen it before.

Comment: @NobleMushtak that cannot be true. Here $B$ has three negative diagonal entries, but there are actually two negatives and a single zero. Please paste the exact quote in a comment.

Comment: "Namely, if $A$ is the symmetric matrix that defines the quadratic form, and $S$ is any invertible matrix such that $D = SAS^T$ is diagonal, then the number of negative elements in the diagonal of $D$ is always the same, for all such $S$; and the same goes for the number of positive elements." EDIT: Oh, wait, I did not notice the words "is diagonal." Sorry about that!

Comment: @NobleMushtak I just put in a 4 by 4 example, easy enough to do the calculations by hand. Recommend you do so, both reading things online and having a computer do calculations are rather passive and do not cement ideas in our heads.

Comment: Yes, I will definitely do this. Thank you for all of your help!